# How to create ListView with Custom Adapter and retrieve database in the listView?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, custom-adapter

I am trying to do a Timetable which a user have to select their subjects and their subjects will be displayed in another activity(ViewTimetable) by clicking the button (See Your Timetable).

After the user have selected his or her subjects, the user will see what have chosen in the same activity(ChooseSubject), and when they click "See Your Timetable", the subjects will be listed in ViewTimetable.java according to the days like "Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri".

If there is no subject on a day for example like Monday, "Monday" will not be shown.

But I have no idea how to retrieve the data from database into the ListView
Please help me! :(

ChooseSubject.java (How I get user's selection)

```
public class ChooseSubject extends ActionBarActivity {

    ArrayList<String> subjects = new ArrayList<String>();

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String[] dbSubject = {
            "INSERT INTO `subjects` VALUES (1,'TPRG343','Introduction to Android Programming')",
            "INSERT INTO `subjects` VALUES (2,'TNWK343(L)','Network Security(Lectural)')",
            "INSERT INTO `subjects` VALUES (3,'TNWK224(L)','System Administration')",
            "INSERT INTO `subjects` VALUES (4,'TWEB334','Advanced Web Design')",
            "INSERT INTO `subjects` VALUES (5,'TWEB224','Web Programming')",
            "INSERT INTO `subjects` VALUES (6,'TNWK343(T)','Network Security(Tutorial)')",
            "INSERT INTO `subjects` VALUES (7,'TMMD233','Multimedia Presentation')",
            "INSERT INTO `subjects` VALUES (8,'TMMD113','Computer Graphics Editing')"

    };

    String[] dbTimetable = {
            "INSERT INTO `timetable` VALUES (1,'Monday','8.30am - 11.30am','KKL','B106')",
            "INSERT INTO `timetable` VALUES (2,'Monday','12.30pm - 2.30pm','GBS','B103/B302')",
            "INSERT INTO `timetable` VALUES (3,'Monday','3.00pm - 6.00pm','GBS','B103/B302')",
            "INSERT INTO `timetable` VALUES (3,'Friday','4.30pm - 6.00pm','GBS','B103/B302')",
            "INSERT INTO `timetable` VALUES (4,'Tuesday','12.00pm - 1.30pm','KKL','B106')",
            "INSERT INTO `timetable` VALUES (4,'Thrusday','10.00am - 1.00pm','KKL','B101')",
            "INSERT INTO `timetable` VALUES (5,'Tuesday','2.00pm - 4.30pm','YKC','B101')",
            "INSERT INTO `timetable` VALUES (5,'Friday','12.00pm - 2.30pm','YKC','B101')",
            "INSERT INTO `timetable` VALUES (6,'Tuesday','4.30pm - 6.00pm','GBS','B103/B207')",
            "INSERT INTO `timetable` VALUES (7,'Wednesday','9.00am - 12.00pm','YKC','B101')",
            "INSERT INTO `timetable` VALUES (8,'Thrusday','1.30pm - 4.30pm','Widura','B101')"

    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_subject);

        db = openOrCreateDatabase("subjects", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("Create table if not exists subjects (id integer primary key, subCode text, subName text)");
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from subjects", null);
        //Access for the first time,
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < dbSubject.length; i++) {
                db.execSQL(dbSubject[i]);
            }
        }
        db.execSQL("Create table if not exists timetable (id integer, day text, time text, lecturer text, class text)");
        Cursor ttCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from timetable", null);
        //Access for the first time,
        if (ttCursor.getCount() == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < dbTimetable.length; i++) {
                db.execSQL(dbTimetable[i]);
            }
        }

        String sId, sCode, sName;
        String output = "";
        Cursor spCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from subjects", null);

        Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(spCursor.getCount()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (spCursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (spCursor.moveToNext()) {
                //output = spCursor.getString(spCursor.getColumnIndex("subCode")) + " \n" + spCursor.getString(spCursor.getColumnIndex("subName"));
                output =  spCursor.getString(spCursor.getColumnIndex("subName"));
                subjects.add(output);
            }
            //
        }

        final LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        Button btnTt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.seeTt);
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        btnTt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent =  new Intent(ChooseSubject.this,ViewTimetable.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Build an AlertDialog
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChooseSubject.this);


                final boolean[] checkedSubjects = new boolean[subjects.size()];
                for(int i = 0 ; i < subjects.size(); i++){
                    checkedSubjects[i] = false;
                }

                // Convert the array to list
                //final List<String> subjects = new ArrayList<String>();

                String[] subjectsOutput = new String[subjects.size()];
                subjectsOutput = subjects.toArray(subjectsOutput);
                final ArrayList<String> selectedItem = new ArrayList<String>();
                //final List<String> subjectList = Arrays.asList(subjects);

                builder.setMultiChoiceItems(subjectsOutput, checkedSubjects, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

                        // Update the current focused item's checked status
                        checkedSubjects[which] = isChecked;

                        if(isChecked){
                            selectedItem.add(String.valueOf(which));

                            db.execSQL("Create table if not exists UserSubject (subName text)");
                            String query = "insert into UserSubject values   ('"+ selectedItem + "');";
                            db.execSQL(query);

                        }


                        else {
                            selectedItem.remove(String.valueOf(which));
                        }
                        // Get the current focused item
                        String currentItem = subjects.get(which);

                        // Notify the current action
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                currentItem + " " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                // Specify the dialog is not cancelable
                builder.setCancelable(false);

                // Set a title for alert dialog
                builder.setTitle("Choose your subjects");

                // Set the positive/yes button click listener
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Do something when click positive button
                        tv.setText("Your subjects are \n");
                        for (int i = 0; i < checkedSubjects.length; i++) {
                            boolean checked = checkedSubjects[i];
                            if (checked) {
                                tv.setText(tv.getText() + "\n" + subjects.get(i) + "\n");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Set the neutral/cancel button click listener
                builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Do something when click the neutral button
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                // Display the alert dialog on interface
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_choose_subject, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

ChooseSubject.xml

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose your subjects"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="See Your Timetable"
        android:id="@+id/seeTt"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

ViewTabletable.java

```
import android.app.ActivityGroup;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ViewTimetable extends ActionBarActivity {

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String id, subCode, subName, day, time, lecturer, myClass;
    String outputTime, outputMon, outputTue, outputWed, outputThur, outputFri;
    LinearLayout layout,box;
    TextView tvTime,tvDetail;

    ArrayList<String> MondaySubject = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> TuesdaySubject = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> WednesdaySubject = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> ThrusdaySubject = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> FridaySubject = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_timetable);

        layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.liLayout);

        db = openOrCreateDatabase("subjects", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
                "select s.id, subCode, s.subName, day, time, lecturer, class" +
                " from subjects s, timetable t, UserSubject us " +
                "where s.id = t.id and us.subName = s.subName",null);


        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                box = new LinearLayout(this);
                box.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                //box.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                //layoutParams.setMargins(35, 10, 35, 10);
                tvTime = new TextView(this);
                tvTime.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

                tvDetail = new TextView(this);

                //box.addView(tvDay);
                box.addView(tvTime);
                box.addView(tvDetail);
                box.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                layout.addView(box);

                id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
                subCode = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subCode"));
                subName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subName"));
                day = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("day"));
                time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time"));
                lecturer = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lecturer"));
                myClass = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("class"));

                if(day.equals("Monday")){
                    outputMon = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subCode")) + "\n" +
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subName")) + "\n" +
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("class")) + "\n" +
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lecturer")) ;
                    outputTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time"));

                    tvTime.setText(outputTime);
                    tvDetail.setText(outputMon);

                }

                if(day.equals("Tuesday")){
                    outputTue = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subCode")) + "\n" +
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subName")) + "\n" +
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("class")) + "\n" +
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lecturer"))  ;
                    outputTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time"));

                    tvTime.setText(outputTime);
                    tvDetail.setText(outputTue);
                }

                if(day.equals("Wednesday")){
                    outputWed = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subCode")) + "\n" +
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subName")) + "\n" +
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("class")) + "\n" +
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lecturer"))  ;
                    outputTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time"));

                    tvTime.setText(outputTime);
                    tvDetail.setText(outputWed);
                }

                if(day.equals("Thursday")){
                    outputThur = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subCode")) + "\n" +
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subName")) + "\n" +
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("class")) + "\n" +
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lecturer"))  ;
                    outputTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time"));

                    tvTime.setText(outputTime);
                    tvDetail.setText(outputThur);
                }

                if(day.equals("Friday")){
                    outputFri  = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subCode")) + "\n" +
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subName")) + "\n" +
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("class")) + "\n" +
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lecturer"))  ;
                    outputTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time"));

                    tvTime.setText(outputTime);
                    tvDetail.setText(outputFri);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

activity_view_timetable.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/liLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where is your Adapter?

Comment: I have no idea how to do it.. Im new to android programming